# the output in buck converter multi sim 14 is too low

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, multisim

it is required to use UC3842 to make a Buck converter that has 68V input and 29 output. i did the calculations for the buck circuit however not for the UC3842. i dont know how to calculate it. i been playing with its values for a while , the max i got was 9.8 volt. any help would be great. best help is telling me how to calculate these values or just telling me the values .
[image: here is a picture of the circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *it is required to use UC3842 to make a Buck converter that has 68V
> input and 29 output.*

Read the "featured" data sheet: -

[image]

Your supply is 68 volts and it will blow the back off the device (and probably the front). Also, it is intended only for low power buck operations without a transistor but, even if it could support an output transistor (for buck operations), using an N channel MOSFET as a source follower is missing the point entirely.

Comment: thanks for this. seriously. because we had to do boost first and it worked , i didnt check the volt limit , and its funny how my professor gave us those numbers